# Can I do this? MYSQL, GROUP_BY WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have:

```
 - 1 - SALTO
 - 1 - SALTO
 - 3 - FRESA
 - 2 - TIMBRE
 - 2 - TIMBRE
```

I need to group by this with mysql but just number 2.
Like this:

```
 - 1 - SALTO
 - 1 - SALTO
 - 3 - FRESA
 - 2 - TIMBRE
```

Comment: What have you done so far - are you able to show us any SQL? Have you heard about the [UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use GROUP BY will next query:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourtablename` GROUP BY `title`;
```

result:

```
1 - SALTO (2)
3 - FRESA (1)
2 - TIMBRE (2)
```

You can't have result as:

```
1 - SALTO
1 - SALTO
3 - FRESA
2 - TIMBRE
```

Comment: Generally spoken `SELECT * ... GROUP BY title` is always **wrong** usage of [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) unless [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) could be used by the database that means the title column has to be unique meaning has to have a primary or unique key